# A Clojure project building several related small tools

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm working on a Clojure project with a common library of functionality, but I want to use this library from a number of small command-line tools.

Let's call them tool1, tool2, tool3.

Each of these tools wraps the bulk of the library.

How should I organize my Clojure source code and what do I need in my project.clj file?

Right now my code is in

```
src/projectname/core.cljc ; a default executable

cljc/projectname/lib1.cljc 
cljc/projectname/lib2.cljc ; cljc because I want to use from clojurescript too later
```

etc.

Where should I put the tool1.clj, tool2.clj etc?

My defproject is

```
(defproject 
   ....
     :aot [projectname.core]
     :main project.core )
```

What do I need to put in to tell it that I want to make the three stand-alone separate, executable tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this [using the lein-exec library](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec).

First, set up ~/bin like this (or similar):

```
> ls -ldF  ~/bin/l*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alan alan 26 Oct 31 08:29 /home/alan/bin/lein -> /home/alan/cool/tools/lein*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alan alan 31 Oct 31 08:29 /home/alan/bin/lein-exec -> /home/alan/cool/tools/lein-exec*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alan alan 33 Oct 31 08:29 /home/alan/bin/lein-exec-p -> /home/alan/cool/tools/lein-exec-p*
```

I have symlinks to the actual files, but you can copy them directly. Make sure ~/bin is in your path, of course.

Then just write an executable clojure "script" like the following. Of course, it must be executable:

```
> ls -l say-hello 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan 212 Nov  2 09:10 say-hello

> cat say-hello

#!/usr/bin/env lein-exec

(defn say-hello [name] 
  (println (format "Hello from the command line, %s!" name)))

(do 
  ; *command-line-args* = <cmd> <arg1> <arg2> ...
  (say-hello (second *command-line-args*)))
```

And off we go!

```
> ./say-hello buckaroo    
Hello from the command line, buckaroo!
```

As for project organization, I would start simple (as with any project!).  Maybe start off with just 1 source file, with different functions as entrypoints for each "script". As the project grows, it'll be easier to see where you would like to break out different namespaces/files.

### Update

You can also do this with `lein uberjar`, and then invoking java directly:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn say-hello [name] 
  (println (format "Hello from the command line, %s!" name)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (say-hello (first args)))

> lein uberjar
Compiling 1 source files to /home/alan/clj/target/uberjar/classes
Compiling clj.core
Created /home/alan/clj/target/uberjar/clj-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /home/alan/clj/target/uberjar/clj-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

> java -jar /home/alan/clj/target/uberjar/clj-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar pardner
Hello from the command line, pardner!
```

So just put the `java` command into a shell script to kick things off. Also note that `:gen-class` is required and that `args` doesn't include the script name anymore.  Of course, you must deploy both the script files and the uberjar.

### Update #2

You can also use this version:

Source:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn say-howdy [args]
  (println (format "Howdy, %s!" (first args))))

(defn give-reply [args]
  (println (format "Back at ya, %s!" (first args))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [method-name  (first  args)
        message      (second args) ]
    (cond 
      (= method-name "say-howdy" ) (say-howdy  (rest args))
      (= method-name "give-reply") (give-reply (rest args))
      :else (throw (NoSuchMethodException. (str "clj.core: invalid method='" method-name \')))))
)
```

scripts:

```
> ls -l say*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan 212 Nov  2 16:24 say-hello
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan 104 Nov  2 16:35 say-howdy
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan 105 Nov  2 16:35 say-reply

> cat ./say-howdy
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /home/alan/clj/target/uberjar/clj-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar say-howdy pardner

> cat ./say-reply 
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /home/alan/clj/target/uberjar/clj-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar give-reply $1
```

Run tools:

```
~/clj > ./say-howdy 
Howdy, pardner!

~/clj > ./say-reply
Back at ya, null!

~/clj > ./say-reply buckaroo
Back at ya, buckaroo!
```

Making the scripts smarter and deciding how to deploy the N scripts and single JAR file is left as an exercise for the reader.

;)

Comment: That's very interesting. But not quite what I was looking for. Is there an advantage to doing it this way over making executables? I'm thinking that this requires having lein etc. set up on the USER (not just developer) machine.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But will I need an uberjar for each tool? (I notice when you run it you don't specify a particular file name within the jar). If so, what do I put in the project.clj to make multiple uberjars?

Comment: Thanks @alan thompson for update #2. Another useful work-around. But would I be right in assuming that what I actually WANT to do ... have Lein create multiple separate executables from a single project ... can't be done for some reason?

Comment: Lein only creates compiled java code (*.class and *.jar files).  The plugin `lein-exec` will compile and execute clojure on-the-fly, but then you need to distribute both the "script" files and lein+java. The above way you need to distribute the script files and uberjar+java.